# removeEventListener not working as expected

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a fairly simple component in my Vue app. When the user opens the menu, I add an event listener to the `#app` element to detect "outside" clicks.

When the user clicks outside, it closes the menu and removes the event listener. This is working as expected. The issue is, when the user clicks the button to open the menu, and then clicks it again to close it, I *also* would like to `removeEventListener` because the menu is now closed.

This however is not working. When I open the menu via the button and then close it via the button the event listener stays on the `#app` element even though I am removing it.

If you click the button multiple times and then click outside of the button while the value displays `true` you will see the console log `outside click` multiple times.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        menuVisible: false
    },
    methods: {
        click(e) {
            var clickSource = e.target;
            var app = document.getElementById("app");
            var that = this;

            function clickOutside(e) {
                if (e.target != clickSource) {
                    console.log("outside click");
                    that.menuVisible = false;
                    app.removeEventListener("click", clickOutside);
                }
            }

            if (this.menuVisible === false) {
                this.menuVisible = true;
                app.addEventListener("click", clickOutside);
            } else if (this.menuVisible === true) {
                this.menuVisible = false;
                app.removeEventListener("click", clickOutside);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}

#app {
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{menuVisible}}
  <button @click="click">
  click
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: At a guess, you're not passing the same function to `removeEventListener` you passed to `addEventListener` (that's nearly the only reason `removeEventListener` wouldn't work; another is calling it on the wrong element, or passing a different third argument), but without going off-site I can't be sure.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry about that, I should know better. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on every `click`, you're creating a **new** `clickOutside` function; if you use that function with `removeEventListener`, since there's no event registration with that *exact* function object, nothing is removed.

Instead, remember the handler object so you can use it for removal, see notes:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        menuVisible: false,
        clickOutside: null
    },
    methods: {
        click(e) {
            var clickSource = e.target;
            var app = document.getElementById("app");
            var that = this;
            
            // Only create it if we don't already have it
            if (!this.clickOutside) {
                // Create it
                this.clickOutside = function clickOutside(e) {
                    console.log("clickOutside triggered");
                    if (e.target != clickSource) {
                        console.log("It's an outside click");
                        that.menuVisible = false;
                        // Remove it
                        app.removeEventListener("click", that.clickOutside);
                    }
                };
            }

            if (this.menuVisible === false) {
                this.menuVisible = true;
                app.addEventListener("click", this.clickOutside);
            } else if (this.menuVisible === true) {
                this.menuVisible = false;
                app.removeEventListener("click", this.clickOutside);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}

#app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{menuVisible}}
  <button @click="click">
  click
  </button>
</div>
```

---

Side note: It's more idiomatic to use

```
if (this.menuVisible) {
    this.menuVisible = false;
    app.removeEventListener("click", this.clickOutside);
} else {
    this.menuVisible = true;
    app.addEventListener("click", this.clickOutside);
}
```

Or even

```
this.menuVisible = !this.menuVisible;
if (this.menuVisible) {
    app.addEventListener("click", this.clickOutside);
} else {
    app.removeEventListener("click", this.clickOutside);
}
```

...rather than comparing a boolean to `true` or `false` with `===`. You already *have* a boolean, so... I mean, where do you stop? `if ((this.menuVisible) === true === true)`? :-)

Comment: Good points on the side note. I certainly have a ways to go in improving my code's "verbose-ness" :/

Answer (score 1):

This feels like an X-Y problem to me. Ideally speaking you should not be dynamically binding/unbinding event listeners in JS (or VueJS even). If you simply want the following behavior:

- Button click toggles the menu
- Click on the app outside the button closes the menu

...then you don't even need messy event handling. The first behavior can be implemented by a simple true/false switch, i.e.

```
this.menuVisible != this.menuVisible
```

Remember to use `.stop` on the `@click` event binder on the button, so you can stop the VueJS click event from bubbling up to the app.

Meanwhile, the second behavior can be done by simply setting `this.menuVisible` to `false`, when a click event is detected on the `#app` but outside the button.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    menuVisible: false
  },
  methods: {
    click(e) {
      console.log('button clicked');
      this.menuVisible = !this.menuVisible;
    },

    appClick(e) {
      console.log('outside clicked');
      this.menuVisible = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app" @click="appClick">
  {{menuVisible}}
  <button @click.stop="click">
  click
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution for my example. However, I created a simplified version of my issue; in reality this functionality exists in a single file Vue component that gets reused throughout the app.

Comment: @justinw Hmmm, I don't see how a single file Vue component will be an issue. Care to elabourate?

Comment: to be honest I am not entirely sure... in the app, `#app` exists in my layout (`default.vue` - I am using nuxt). The menu component referenced in this question is used more than a few times throughout the app and always by other components. For example `appHeader.vue` imports my menu component. So I thought that if I created the `appClick` method in the `default.vue` layout, I would need to pass it down to `appHeader` as a prop and then the menu component as a prop and redo that for all the components that use the menu component. Again, I am new to Vue so I could be/probably am wrong.

Comment: If `menuVisible` is a global app state and you do not want to pass it down as a prop to all your menu components, then you will have to look into using VueX for state management. But yes, if you do not want to keep track of a global state using VueX, you will have to pass `menuVisible` to all your menu props (which can be cumbersome, especially if your menu component is nested several component levels deep).

Comment: Yeah that was my basic thought process, glad it was confirmed by someone with more experience.